# *** Can't find 22.78.224.10.in-addr.arpa.: No answer

Tags: linux, dns, centos

I really need some assistance. I have set up a DNS server with Centos 6.10. When I test my server's address, I get an error.

Here are my configurations.

```
    #named.conf

    cat /etc/named.conf
    //
    // named.conf
    
    
    options {
            listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.224.78.22; };
    #       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
            directory       "/var/named";
            dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
            statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
            memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
            allow-query     { localhost; 10.224.78.0/24; };
            recursion yes;
            empty-zones-enable yes;
            dnssec-enable yes;
            dnssec-validation yes;
            dnssec-lookaside auto;
    
            /* Path to ISC DLV key */
            bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    
            managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    };
    
    logging {
            channel default_debug {
                    file "data/named.run";
                    severity dynamic;
            };
    };
    
    zone "." IN {
            type hint;
            file "named.ca";
    };
    
    include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
    include "/etc/named.root.key";
    
    #named.rfc1912.zones
    
     cat /etc/named.rfc1912.zones
    // named.rfc1912.zones:
    //
    // Provided by Red Hat caching-nameserver package
    //
    // ISC BIND named zone configuration for zones recommended by
    // RFC 1912 section 4.1 : localhost TLDs and address zones
    // and http://www.ietf.org/internet-drafts/draft-ietf-dnsop-default-local-zones-02.txt
    // (c)2007 R W Franks
    //
    // See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
    //
    
    zone "global.cs" IN {
            type master;
            file "global.cs";
            allow-update { 10.224.78.0/24; };
    };
    
    zone "localhost" IN {
            type master;
            file "named.localhost";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
    
    zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" IN {
            type master;
            file "named.loopback";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
    
    zone "78.224.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
            type master;
            file "db.78.224.10";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
    
    
    zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
            type master;
            file "named.empty";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
    
    #Zone directe
    
     cat /var/named/global.cs
    $TTL 3H
    @       IN SOA  serverdns.global.cs. root.serverdns.global.cs. (
                                            0       ; serial
                                            1D      ; refresh
                                            1H      ; retry
                                            1W      ; expire
                                            3H )    ; minimum
    @               IN      NS      serverdns.global.cs.
    @               IN      A       10.224.78.22
    serverdns       IN      A       10.224.78.22
    www             IN      CNAME   serverdns.global.cs.
    
    #Zone inverse
    
     cat /var/named/db.78.224.10
    $TTL 3H
    @       IN SOA  serverdns.global.cs. root.serverdns.global.cs. (
                                            0       ; serial
                                            1D      ; refresh
                                            1H      ; retry
                                            1W      ; expire
                                            3H )    ; minimum
    @               IN      NS      serverdns.global.cs.
    @               IN      PTR     global.cs.
    global.cs       IN      PTR     10.224.78.22
    6               IN      PTR     serverdns.global.cs.
    
    
    nslookup serverdns
    Server:         10.224.78.22
    Address:        10.224.78.22#53
    
    Name:   serverdns.global.cs
    Address: 10.224.78.22
    
     nslookup 10.224.78.22
    Server:         10.224.78.22
    Address:        10.224.78.22#53
    
    *** Can't find 22.78.224.10.in-addr.arpa.: No answer
```

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenu sur Superuser! Traduisez votre question en Anglais. Cela permettra à plusieurs de vous répondre. Et plus important parce que la langue officielle du site est l'anglais.

Comment: J’ai traduit votre question. S’il y a des mots ou phrases qui sont mal compris, vous avez le droit de les changer.

Comment: Merci pour les conseils

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you test the server's configuration?

Comment: nslookup serverdns
    Server:         10.224.78.22
    Address:        10.224.78.22#53
    
    Name:   serverdns.global.cs
    Address: 10.224.78.22
----------------------------------    
     nslookup 10.224.78.22
    Server:         10.224.78.22
    Address:        10.224.78.22#53
    
    *** Can't find 22.78.224.10.in-addr.arpa.: No answer